# templateUrl fails on a Component decorator in angular 2 - is prefixing extra double quote '%E2%80%9C' to url

Tags: angular, urlencode, angular2-template

I have a LoginComponent class that has a Component decorator in Angular 2 (RC1).

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector: "login",
    templateUrl: "login-view.html"   // Right here
})
```

When the LoginComponent is loaded by the browser, it will fetch the template at the given template Url as defined above.

What I am seeing is that the template GET is returning a 404.  Upon closer inspection, I am seeing that the request url is:

```
http://localhost:3000/%E2%80%9C/login-view.html
```

I looked up the encoding and found that '%E2%80%9C' is a left double quote.

Any ideas on how there is an extra double quote here?  Am I doing something wrong here?

I am seeing this using Angular 2, RC1, on the Chrome browser.

Comment: `templateUrl` has to be relative to your `index.html` and not to your component file. is this true for your url?

Comment: This might have to do with the relative URL support in the RC. If you are using commonjs modules, try adding 'moduleId: module.id' to your component metadata.

Comment: @lexith - thanks for your response, but no matter what path i provide to templateUrl, I am getting the double left quote (uri encoded) prefix.

Comment: @awiseman - no luck with the module.id.  (I also needed to change my tsconfig from systemjs to common, in order to get common style module generation); still no luck.