# RouteConfig in router-depracted in Angular 2 is prepending a few extra '%E2%80%9C' double left quotes to the redirect route

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, systemjs, routeconfig

I have an angular 2 app (built with Angular RC1) that is using the class RouteConfig from the router-deprecated module of RC1.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";
import {RouteConfig, RouterOutlet} from "@angular/router-deprecated";
import {LoginComponent} from "./login/login";

@RouteConfig([
  {path: "/", redirectTo: ["Login"]},
  {
    path: "/login",
    component: LoginComponent,
    name: "Login"
 }])
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: "<router-outlet></router-outlet>",
  directives: [RouterOutlet]
})
export class AppComponent {
}
```

As seen above, when the user hits localhost:3000 on the browser, I am seeing the browser url redirect to:

```
http://localhost:3000/%E2%80%9C/%E2%80%9C/%E2%80%9C/login
```

I am seeing a related issue with Component decorator templateUrls.
  [Here's my other stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37471855/templateurl-fails-on-a-component-decorator-in-angular-2-is-prefixing-extra-dou)

I must be missing or doing something wrong here.  Any ideas?

I suspect it might have to do with the config SystemJS?

Comment: You might be missing the `<base href="/">` in `<head>` or use `PathLocationStrategy` (default) with a server that doesn't support it.

Comment: @günter-zöchbauer - I do have the `<base href="/">` tag.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?
For me (RC1, deprecated router) , a " is inserted on all routes.. it's annoying.. have no idea how to fix it

Comment: I might add that the issue was not resolved by switching to the new router.. still the same.. weird

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was that the

```
<base href="/">
```

tag was using a stylized character encoding for the double quotes. I (shamefully) admit that I must have copied the tag from a tutorial and did not sanitize the double quote character; lesson learned.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/05/angular2-release-candidate-1-rc1-changes/), I think the fix is to change 'RouteConfig' to 'Routes' and remove the 'name' property from any route definitions placed in that array.